# price of developer license for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does Microsoft offer developer license for professionals and students? Is there a special student program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're simply interested in developing using the emulator, there is no license fee to pay. Just download the tools and go to town.

Scott Guthrie actually has a good write-up of all the tools you'll need to download (for free) and how to get started:

[Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools Released - ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/16/windows-phone-7-developer-tools-released.aspx)

Registering for the Marketplace to sell your apps is another story. You will have to pay a $99 fee to create your account there unless you are a student participating in [Microsoft's DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) program (in which case the registration is free there as well).

Comment: thank you, but I would like to know really the develop license to put at marketplace.

Comment: ok, thank you.
If you know if the cost of student and company are the same, I would be pleased.

Answer (score 6):

To develop applications, it's free.

But if you need to know the price to submit your apps to the marketplace:

Check out [Windows Development App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/membership)

It's $99 US Dollers or £65 in the UK.

That allows you to submit 5 applications. It is $19.99 for each app after that. If you are a student, you get a load of tools free. You can access the student membership via the link above.

Comment: that's not strictly true - all the tools are free - you can use vs2010 express with the wp7 tools to create the applications

Answer (score 2):

the registration prices are here ($99) - http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/membership

there is a great blog post about how to get from concept to marketplace here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/11/15/windows-phone-7-apps-getting-from-concept-to-customer.aspx